# Spring state machine annotation @WithStateMachine not working when created in wrong order

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I'm using the spring state machine and want to add on functionality to transitions and state changes using @WithStateMachine, @OnTransition and @OnStateChanged to keep the class with @EnableStateMachine as simple as possible. I never got it to work though and after some trial and error I realised that the @WithStateMachine bean has to be created before the state machine but that dependency isn't automatically solved.

The interesting parts of my project basically boils down to the following:

```
package org.myorg.a

@Component
public class MyComponent {

    @Autowired
    StateMachine<States, Events> sm;

}

package org.myorg.b

@WithStateMachine
public class Listener {

    @OnTransition
    public void anyTransition() {}
}
```

MyComponent and therefore the state machine will be created before the Listener because Spring will look in package a before package b and in effect none of the methods in class Listener will be associated with the state machine and the anyTransition method will never be called.

The only two solutions to this that I can think of is

- Rename the packages
- Annotate the @EnableStateMachine class with @DependsOn and explicitly depend on all @WithStateMachine classes

In my opinion neither of those two solutions are good. Does anyone have a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this just got fixed in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/232.